# Can I enter the Schengen area for a time period that spans two visa validity periods?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, customs-and-immigration

I have a Schengen visa that expires on the 25th of June on my old passport & I have another visa on my new passport that begins on the 26th of June (one day after the expiry date  of my old visa). My arrival date at Germany is on the 25th of June . Can I enter the country without facing any issues?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Nope, that's not the case. My visa expires on the same day of arrival and the other one starts the next day + the old visa is on my expired passport.

Comment: x @Meme: That's exactly the kind of back-to-back visas the old question is about. For one of them being in an expired passport, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95686/can-i-use-the-valid-schengen-visa-in-old-passport

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you. But, my question is will my arrival on the *same* day of the visa's expiry date cause any problems? I'm afraid that they might send me back, I definitely don't want that to happen.