# Facing issues With my visa. Need quick reply

Tags: schengen-visas

actually I have a passport which expires in September and I got a new one as they told me that I won’t be allowed to use the passport anywhere 5months before the expiration. So I got a new passport and then applied for a Shenzhen visa.  But the embassy has put my new visa on my old canceled passport and sent it to me. I need to travel tonight and I don’t know what to do. Pls help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use the valid Schengen visa in old passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95686/can-i-use-the-valid-schengen-visa-in-old-passport). Expect to get downvoted when you use words like urgent reply needed etc. Nobody is paid to give quick replies. In any case your question has been asked several times here and been answered.

Comment: Could you clarify if that is Shenzhen (China) or Schengen (Europe)?

Comment: Schengen europe

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get competent advise here, and you can't reach the embassy on a Saturday (which would be the most reasonable approach if they are open), you could go to the airport - if the airline doesn't let you board, that answers your question, and if they let you board then it is most likely that China will let you enter (because otherwise the airline wouldn't have let you on board).

Obviously bring your old passport with the visa, and your new passport.