# Travel to Romania with valid Schengen visa in my old passport

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, romania

I am an Omani national. Recently I renewed my passport because its expiry was  in less than 6 months. I have a valid Schengen visa in my old passport for another 3 months. Now I want to travel to Romania for a week. Is it possible to take my two passports and use the Schengen visa in my cancelled/old passport for entry into Romania?

Comment: Closely related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95686/can-i-use-the-valid-schengen-visa-in-old-passport. Schengen visas on old passports are considered valid by Schengen states. Romania is not a Schengen state but allows entry to double/multi-entry valid Schengen visa holders.