# valid Schengen visa on expired passport

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

Can I travel to France & Italy with a valid schengen visa issued for business purpose by Netherlands in an expired passport . Biometrics done in 2018. Visa is valid till 2021 with multiple entry allowed.

Now I am travelling to France & Italy with family as a tourist. Is the visa valid for entry into these countries

Comment: Did you use the visa for the trip/purpose for which it was originally issued?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here I don’t know how to flag or mark this as duplicate though maybe someone can help

[already answered](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95686/can-i-use-the-valid-schengen-visa-in-old-passport)